# Visualizing Time Series Data Sampled at 244hz, on the browser

Tags: canvas, d3.js, svg, three.js, webgl

I have been attempting to plot six channels of ECG signal data onto a browser screen. The signals have been sampled at 244Hz, to make sure that the signal can capture variations of 122Hz.

I have made a D3 version of it (svg) There are few opensource components out there like https://www.physionet.org/lightwave/.

So my concern is that if you take 10 seconds of data, you are looking at 2440 data points per signal x 6 channels which are 14640 points to be plotted on the screen. If you have annotations (an ECG marker saying a specific tag to a part of a wave ) you are looking at 14640 points in 6 signals, and about 30 vertical lines (ECG markers). Given this high number of points to be plotted on SVG the component struggles with basic pan and zoom, even on Chrome. (If i reduce the number of points it works smooth ! )

Questions

1. Is D3 the right choice
2. How to use D3 with HTML5 Canvas ( would this make better sense? )
3. Is WebGL worth Exploring?
4. What about other frameworks like paperjs, threejs and the like

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n2enn80o/ is an example i created with 1 signal of 2 seconds worth of data

Comment: There are several line simplification algorithms that will run in real time and ease the rendering load. You can set the level of simplification dependent on zoom. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm Also the number of lines to display is not dependent on the data source but on the display resolution, you can not see more than the screen can present so ignore data that can not be displayed.